# Instantiate a vc keeping the navigation bar Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to present `NewMapViewController` when responding to a remote notification action, but if I instantiate directly `NewMapViewController` I loose the navigation bar. If I instead instantiate the navigationController and perform a segue than I see all the view controllers ( splash and login) showing up one after the other, and it's quite unpleasant. Is there a way to keep the navigation bar in `NewMapViewController` and avoid showing all the view controllers in cascade? As always many thanks for your help.

This is what I tried :

```
case Id.checkActionIdentifier:
            print("Check tapped")
            let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
            if let routeToCheck = userInfo[NSLocalizedString("Route", comment: "")] as? String {
                RoutesArray.routeName = routeToCheck
//                print("rotta is: \(routeToCheck)")
            }
//            let content = response.notification.request.content
//            print(" Body \(content.body)")
//            print(" Title \(content.title)")
            NewMapViewController.routeCheckCounter = 1

            //  Goes to NewMapViewController but showing the splash and login VC first
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController : UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            let vc = initialViewController.viewControllers[0]
            vc.performSegue(withIdentifier: "alertToMapSegue", sender: nil)

            // goes straight to NewMapViewController but looses nav bar
//            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
//            let initialViewController : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewMapViewController") as! NewMapViewController
//            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
//            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

UPDATE:

I have been able to avoid the passage through the login vc but still shows the splash screen before `NewMapViewController` with the code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewMapViewController") as UIViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController?.show(vc, sender: self)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems `window`s `rootViewController` is already a `UINavitationController` so you can simply grab that as below and push the `NewMapViewController`.

```
 case Id.checkActionIdentifier:
     let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
     if let routeToCheck = userInfo[NSLocalizedString("Route", comment: "")] as? String {
         RoutesArray.routeName = routeToCheck
     }
     NewMapViewController.routeCheckCounter = 1

     if let navigationVC = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
         let main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
         let newMapVC = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewMapViewController") as! NewMapViewController
         navigationVC.pushViewController(newMapVC, animated: true)
     }
```

Comment: Thank you. I still get the splash screen showing up as in my update code but I just want  the app to launch on `NewMapViewController` the tapping on the action button . Is there a way to avoid showing it?

Comment: I don't think you can do much about it as the splash screen(or the latest screenshot OS captures) is shown by the OS on resuming the app.

Comment: I see, so I'll just have to stick with it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Karman I just found out that this way to get to `NewMapViewController` cause a weird behaviour in a function. This function gets called if the `NewMapViewController.routeCheckCounter' is greater than 0.  It loads a route, displays it as a `MKPolyline` and resizes the view to zoom on it. Since the change in the question it doesn't set the region anymore. Do you have clue about why? I mean the rest of the function does it's job correctly.